# Show relationship summary using Entity Reference

Tags: views

First question, hope I can get some answers. I have this information schema:

**Books**: Title and Author (Entity Reference field to Books content type)

**Author**: Name and Books (Entity Reference field to Author content type)

I created a view to show the authors with their ID's. I want to also show in the Books field the ID's for the books that reference them. I already created the relationship and turned aggregation on and asigned it to the books field. The view looks like it's working and aggregation also seems to be working, however, no results are showing in the books field. Any ideas?

I'll appreciate any answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you only need an entity reference field on the content type *Books* that points to *Author* in your example. It would be a pain in the long run to manually maintain the two relationships and all data needed to describe your relationship is given in the *Book->Author* field.

Now let's create a View that lists books.

[image: Views Entity Reference Group by title]

*(I've removed the second column in the screenshot from Views as no settings were done there)*

Add the entity reference relationship under *Relationships*.
Add Content: title and use your relationship.
Under Format and Settings, set group by to the *Content: Title* field you created in the step before.

Now all books are listed and grouped by their author.

In my example I also sort by the authors name. If you rather show the Nid of the content, just switch from *Content: Title* to *Content: Nid*.